# Error while getting data from aerospike in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, aerospike

I am running following code in python 2.7 and it is giving error even though data is there:

```
AEROSPIKE_CONN_SETTINGS = {
    'hosts': [ ('127.0.0.1', 3000) ]
}
import aerospike
client = aerospike.client(AEROSPIKE_CONN_SETTINGS).connect()
key = ('segment', 'test', 'b5d135f7f66412')
client.exists(key)
```

output=> 
(('segment',
  'test',
  'b5d135f7f66412',
  bytearray(b'\x18\xef\xd4\xd1\xd7\xb6\xc1Ha')),
 {'gen': 1, 'ttl': 695})

but for

```
client.get(key)
```

ERROR => **ClientError: (-1L, 'Unable to call loads function', 'src/main/serializer.c', 480)**

Please note that the same code works fine for python 3.5
and it is not working for python 2.7 (above error)

**EDIT: Just realized this error is comming when I putting data with python 3.5 script and reading with python 2.7**

Comment: I guess you answered your own question. Seems python 2.7 is not able to decode object written by 3.5. I am not surprised. Does the reverse also happen? If yes, I would be surprised.

Comment: Thanks Sunil I got it.
Yes 3.5 is able to decode 2.7 and works fine.